# Invalid URI: The format of the URI cannot be determined

Tags: c#, ftp, webrequest

I am trying to create a folder and upload files via FTP, but I get the following error:

> Invalid URI: The format of the URI cannot be determined

I look for the web solution but nothing works so far

```
<add key="FTP" value="ftp://192.168.1.1:21" />


string ftpURI = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FTP"];

string nombre = (ftpURI);

WebRequest ftpRequest = WebRequest.Create(nombre + @"//Images//test");
ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("rmorquecho@xxx.com", "12345*");
using (var resp = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(resp.StatusCode);
                    }
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I intend to verify if the folder exists and if I don't create it

Comment: the problem seem to be the value of "nombre", who come from you appsettings "FTP". Inspect the value... If you cannot understand, please show us the value of you FTP appsettings

Comment: The "FTP" configuration value is apparently not a valid URI...

Comment: I edit question, with the data

Comment: `ftp://192.168.1.1:21//Images//test` is not a valid URI.  Are you trying to escape the `/`?

Comment: ok I check it, and see if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FTP"]` is an invalid URI. You need to fix that.

You probably need to add ftp to the url in the app settings.
Like this "ftp://192.168.1.1:21"

In the end call `GetResponse`

```
using (var resp = (FtpWebResponse) ftpRequest.GetResponse()){
        Console.WriteLine(resp.StatusCode);
}
```

`nombre + @"//Images//test"` does not create a valid url. You are using double `/`

Also make sure directory `Images` exists.

Comment: Okay, how do I fix it or why do I change it?

Comment: Okay, come in, but still don't create the folder :(

Comment: No, just pass by connect to FTP but don't believe it ... add this:

Comment: WebRequest ftpRequest = WebRequest.Create(nombre + @"//Test");

Comment: Remote server error: (550) File unavailable (eg file not found or not accessed

Comment: Edit your question and show us the exact string in WebRequest.Create

Comment: ready, edit the question

Comment: see my answer. Did it work?